# Why is my RAM usage so high with nothing running?

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-usage

Is it normal for a computer with nothing running to have an 19% memory usage?

I know it may not be a huge problem but I'm concern because with a game like Modern Warfare I have 80%+ usage and I might run out of memory.

Tell me if you need more information.

Task Manager programs memory usage:

[image: Task Manager programs memory usage]

Task Manager memory usage:

[image: Task Manager memory usage]

Comment: "Nothing running"? No way, there is always plenty of OS-related stuff going on, perhaps 50 or more processes (i.e. programs) running, whether you started them or not. And they all use some memory.

Comment: only 3GB/16GB of memory is being used which is just nothing, why are you worrying? The more memory you have the more Windows will use for prefetching and caches to accelerate application loading

Comment: How to add a good inline image that improves the question.  Copy and paste in the body. Windows has an inbuilt hotkey (Win + Shift + S) which executes Snipping Tool. Any screen captured will be copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Windows 10 system requirements is ...

> [RAM: 1 gigabyte (GB) for 32-bit or 2 GB for 64-bit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028142/windows-10-system-requirements)

So, Windows needs at least 2 GB RAM to run itself and taking other apps like Chrome into account running alongside, 3GB RAM allocated seems to be due to Windows 2GB plus other apps in the RAM.